# How can we loop over drive changes upto a pageToken?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have to retrieve my file changes upto a particular time.i can see Google provide drive changes api which will give me changes after any start page token. But the requirement is to get history changes...can anyone please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Changes are always tracked relative to a start token, that's how the service works.

In other words, what you want to do is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to call [getStartPageToken](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/getStartPageToken) and track changes from that moment, there is no other way around it. Otherwise there are no changes to track.

Depending on what specific information do you want to track, [Revision methods](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) might get you what you want. For each file you can get a list of historical Revisions by calling [Revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) and for each individual revision you can get information like modified time, modifying user or links to the version of the file by calling [Revisions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get).

I hope this is of any help.